# How do I print out the whole text file all at once and not on the second time?

Tags: java, io

I am not sure what went wrong but the printout only give me completely the information form the txt file only on the second time.  The first time it will only print out the first line that is in my txt file.  Hope someone can point out my mistake.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
   try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("data_file/Contact.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String currentContact = in.readLine();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
        while(currentContact != null) {   
            StringBuilder current = sb.append(currentContact);
            current.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contact  : \n" + current);
            // System.out.println("Contact:" + currentContact);                    
            currentContact = in.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for me.  Maybe you could edit your post to make it more clear what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contact  : \n" + current);
```

outside your while loop (and change it to use `sb` rather than `current`). That will show the dialog only after the whole file has been read. Right now you're showing a dialog for each line in your input file.

Incidentally, you could replace this:

```
StringBuilder current = sb.append(currentContact);
current.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

with this:

```
sb.append(currentContact);
sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

or even do it on one line:

```
sb.append(currentContact).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

`StringBuffer.append` returns the object that it is called on. This allows you to chain calls to `append`.

Comment: Hi, I did as you told but it's still not working.  Anyway, to add on my txt file only have this 2 lines:  Bugs Bunny 22 OnShelf  and the 2nd line : Gatsby 10 OnShelf.  The programs on invoked only show the first line.  And the 2nd time, 2 lines will then appeared all at once.